# Can we send location request to other android phone via bluetooth...?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am new to android developing world. I am making an app where I need to send location request to people who are in my contact list. If the request is accepted, then he/ she will respond with current location. While responding he will also collect neighboring device latitude and longitude via Bluetooth.

Till now what I am completed is turning on neighboring device bluetooth programmatically and getting current location latitude and longitude only.

I am not getting how to send request through android application to other device and get the response.

Please brief me about the concept and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this example.
Bluetooth Chat
https://mega.co.nz/#!s0kmWYKD!W2BkCRyUwtidS0DmRoWi43HgyGh72j9pqZPpklvT_eQ

All is inside the example.
First you have to make a connection with the device who want to connect then change the function "sendMessage()" and putting the location in "message".